# my undo doesn't work in 2.8, except in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

Since a week, when I undo in object mode, sculpt mode or in the properties panels (in fact in all editors I tested except edit mode), it doesn't undo in the mode, but instead it enter the edit mode of the last object I edited and undo there.

Also it destroy the work I've done since the last time I was in edit mode. So my blender is totally unusable.
I'm downloading every daily build since a week in the hope it corrects but it doesn't. I also found that my previous 2.8 builds doesn't work anymore and that my 2.79 bender just works fine. So I guess it might have something to do with the user preferences. I have no idea.

I didn't found anyone with a similar problem, and no bug report refers to it.
It isn't a keyboard problem since I tested to undo by the menus, and `ctrl+z` just works fine in edit mode. It repeats with every new files I create and in older too.

[image: gif for clarity I hope]

The one who solve my problem is awesome, and thanks to anyone that gives a guess

Comment: If you do ctrl + alt + z for undo history what shows up? Does it show the movement?

Comment: it works fine on my version so I don't know maybe you are confused because the undo in 2.80 behaves a bit different from the previous version as for now it literally undo's everything you did step by step. while before in blender 2.79 it was per Mode.

Comment: ctrl + alt + z doesn't seem to do do anything in 2.8, I don't know if it is just me

Comment: It is weirder than just diferent behaviour, when I want to undo a sculpt stroke in sculpt mode for example, it shouldn't undo in edit mode and lose all what I sculpted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the described behavior is no longer relevant to Blender 2.80 series

Comment: @aliasguru Why would that make it off-topic?

Comment: @RayMairlot Because the question here was asked when 2.80 was still in early alpha or beta stage,where Undo was not working the way it did in 2.79 (Global Undo was disabled by default in 2.80 alpha or beta). Many questions like this one popped up as a consequence, and the defaults were changed back to Global Undo. It's kind of confusing to still have this question around, when hundreds of others regarding Blender 2.80 alpha and beta had been closed as off topic because it was about beta software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is (and in 2.79 also have been) two Undo handling behaviors, which can be triggered using the **Global Undo** property in the Preferences. Go to your Preferences, navigate to Editing, and make sure Global Undo is checked there to get back to the undo behavior you are used to:

[image: undo prefs]

In 2.79, when Global Undo is unchecked, only edit mode changes would be recorded on the Undo Stack. Object mode changes then cannot be undone. In 2.80, at the moment the behavior you described is used, but this might change until final release.

Answer (score 3):

In Blender 2.8 this is not "Editing" but "System" tab in Preferences

[image]