# Blender 2.8 Undo History

Tags: 3d-view

I'm trying out Blender 2.8 and can't find Undo History. The online manual for Blender 2.80 > User Interface > Tools > Undo & Redo says"There is also an Undo History of the last actions taken, recorded by Blender. You can access the history pop-up with Ctrl-Alt-Z."
Ctrl-Alt-Z does not produce the History box.

Comment: [Somewhat Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124798/my-undo-doesnt-work-in-2-8-except-in-edit-mode)

Answer (score 6):

In v2.80.44, Edit > 'Undo History'

[image: Edit > 'Undo History']

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut, just right click on Edit-> Undo History -> Change Shortcut.