# How to undo only one specific action

Tags: modeling, actions

Let's say I have an object that I am working on, and I want to undo one specific modifier that I have applied to it a while back. Is there a way to only undo that one specific action? This would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender 2.8 Undo History](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130373/blender-2-8-undo-history)

Comment: No. That undoes the entire history after that. I'm looking to *actually* undo only one specific action. In fact, here's an example: I apply 2 subsurfs, and one mirror, and I want to unapply the first subsurf without unapplying the other one and the mirror.

Comment: Consider adding this to your q. Answer is no, undo list is the only option you have, all or nothing...

Comment: The power of modifiers lies in keeping them live, so you can non destructively tweak their actions. If you needlessly apply them you are trowing it all out the window.

Comment: I was giving an example, but point taken.

Comment: Actually not the case with boolean.